# when clicking on a class append the element

Tags: javascript, html

*i fixed the old question ty for helping this is my second question* 

There's one more thing i need to know. How can i select a child of "user chat_user"?

```
        var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("user chat_user");
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var anchor = anchors[i];
    anchor.onclick = function() { setTimeout(function() {
        var ok = document.getElementsByClassName("user-dropdown")[0];
        var za = document.createElement("li");
        za.className = "user-dropdown-entry";
        za.innerText = "Mention";
        ok.append(za);}, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that there is no element with class `user-dropdown`\

Comment: but if i add setTimeout to "ok" it doesnt say anything

Comment: Don't post the code in comments. **edit** your quesion. OR maybe create a code-snippet

Comment: ok its now fine i think

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have any element with the class user-dropdown.

Comment: ah my bad.. sec

Comment: okey i added the right one

Comment: I just tested it in jsfiddle with the updated html and it works. You might want to move the onclick event handler function outside the loop, and just reference it in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ensure your element is defined/exists.

Try this:

```js
let ok = document.querySelector(".user-dropdown");
// Ensure the class `.user-dropdown` exists
if (ok) {
  // Only loop through how many exist, no more
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("user chat_user")).forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.onclick = () => {
      // Use querySelector to select only the first of child here
      let za = document.createElement("li");
      za.className = "user-dropdown-entry";
      za.innerText = "Mention";
      ok.append(za);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.user.chat_user {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<dive class="user-dropdown">user dropdown</div>
  <ul class="messages">
    <li class="chat_msg msg-user-message">
      <div class="colorbar user"></div>
      <span class="user chat_user">
    <span class="chat_user_prof">
    <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/e8/e852c40b62be21a16b9f6d69a584e742d7364abb.jpg"></span>
      <span class="xp_70">
    <i class="icon"></i>
    <span class="level_val">79</span>
      </span>
      <a class="chat_user_name">ChickenİX * 1</a>
      <span class="chat_user_ico">
    <i class="icon-gammdom-symbol"></i>
    <span class="chat_user_colen">:</span>
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="chat_cont">İg diyon xd</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: i want to do this:

When i click the "user chat_user" it should do these;
 let za = document.createElement("li");
      za.className = "user-dropdown-entry";
      za.innerText = "Mention";
      ok.append(za);

Comment: i fixed it ty. could you please help me to my second question?

Comment: To see the children, just `console.log(anchor.children)` inside of the loop and do with it what you want

Comment: also how can i select the clicked class' innerText

Comment: Just do `el.innerText`

Comment: VM314:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: el is not defined. And i dont have any class or var named "el"

Comment: anchor.innerText results the last element. i want to clicked class with name  "user chat_user" 's innerText

Comment: If you have more questions please post a new question as this is already out of scope